# Core Data versioning and SVN

Tags: objective-c, xcode, svn, core-data, version-control

I use Xcode Repositories for working with svn, and today i added a new version to my Core Data Model and tried to commit it. But Xcode through an error:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Entry for '/Users/user/Desktop/project/Core Data/Translator.xcdatamodeld/Translator 2.0.xcdatamodel/contents' is marked as 'copied' but is not itself scheduled
for addition.  Perhaps you're committing a target that is
inside an unversioned (or not-yet-versioned) directory?
```

I think that the problem is that svn treates xcdatamodel as a dolder, and since it is changed it doesn's under version control anymore. But what should i do then? Don't commit new models and transfer it manually?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend writing a subversion checkout/commit hook that would create a zip or tar archive of the Translator.xcdatamodeld directory, and then check that in. The actual xcdatamodeld directory would be ignored. (It would probably be best *not* to compress the archive, since compressing will just make it harder for svn to compute diffs and make your repository larger.)

Comment: Thank you, that's a really nice hook)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when you start with the first data model, Xcode creates a file, let's say:
    myProject.xcdatamodeld

Let's say that you create, via menu *Editor > Add Model Version*, a second version of the model named _myProject_v2_. What Xcode actually does is: it creates a folder, named as your original model, and copies the original model in a subfolder, then creates a second subfolder with a file containing the new version:

```
myProject.xcdatamodeld
    |
    +- myProject.xcdatamodel
    |           |
    |           +- contents (a file containing the actual model)
    |
    +- myProject_v2.xcdatamodel
                |
                +- contents (a file containing the 2nd version of the model)
```

So SVN gets confused, because what he thinks is a file (the original myProject.xcdatamodeld) and which is stored in SVN, is now a folder, with subfolders. 
And moreover, these subfolders, being created by XCode, gets eventually their hidden *.svn* folder.. so my solution is:

1. delete folder *myProject.xcdatamodeld* from SVN
2. do a commit of the rest
3. close Xcode and rename your folder project: eh: _projectFolder_old_
4. do a checkout of the project, which hopefully will not have a *myProject.xcdatamodeld*
5. from within xcode, create a bogus data model named *myProject*. Don't create anything in the model, it's useless
6. version it, with *Editor > Add Model Version*
7. close XCode
8. open in Finder your old datamodel in *myProject.xcdatamodeld* (right mouse button, *Show package contents*)
9. open in Finder your original model and copy the *contents* file from *projectFolder_old/myProject.xcdatamodeld/myProject.xcdatamodel* to the new project: *projectFolder/myProject.xcdatamodeld/myProject.xcdatamodel*  (you will need to do a couple of *Show Package Contents*
10. repeat for your second version, copy the *contents* file from *projectFolder_old/myProject.xcdatamodeld/myProject_v2.xcdatamodel* to the new project: *projectFolder/myProject.xcdatamodeld/myProject_v2.xcdatamodel*
11. reopen Xcode and check everything is correct
12. add to svn the files, if not already added, and do a commit